# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

This script makes a github repo from command line
I have a file not found error. I cannot seem to solve it. any help is appreciated.

tried exception errors

Script:

```
import sys, os, subprocess, os.path

class git_script:
    def __init__(self, dir_path):
        self.dir_path = dir_path

    def git_func(self):
        os.mkdir(dir_path)
        os.chdir(dir_path)
        os.system('git init && touch README.md && git add && git commit -m "Initial Commit" ')
        os.system("curl --user thisisshub https://api.github.com/orgs/orgname/repos -d {'name':'newreponame'}")
        os.system('git push -u origin master')

dir_path = os.path.join("~/Downloads/Projects/" , input('Repository name: '))
final_path = git_script(dir_path)
final_path.git_func()
```

Error:

```
$ python some.py                                                                                                 1 ↵
Repository name: automation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "some.py", line 16, in <module>
    final_path.git_func()
  File "some.py", line 8, in git_func
    os.mkdir(dir_path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Downloads/Projects/automation'
```

Comment: `os.mkdir()` won't create intermediate directories. Do `Downloads` and `Downloads/Projects` already exist? Also, I don't think it will process "~" the way the shell does. You probably need to consult the HOME environment variable to create the pathname (`os.environ["HOME"]`)

Comment: yes the Downloads/Projects does exist. i'll change the ~ to /home/user/ and report the changes

Comment: the problem was ~ is not recognized by python as you said, /home/user/ is the way to go. thanks James!

Answer (score 0):

> `os.mkdir(dir_path)` will create the given directory only, but it will
>   not create the intermediate directory in the given path.
>
> For example: `dir_path = "~/Downloads/Project/repo_name"` this will
>   throw error.

Solution:

`os.makedirs(dir_path)` will create the directory on a given path. Also, if any intermediate-level directory doesn’t exist then it will create that too.